# How to select whole li that contains a textarea contained in a div within another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Basically what I have is this:

```html
<ul id="carrerLadderList" class="gw-ul-sortable ui-sortable">
<li class="gw-sortable-handle ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <textarea data-content-index="-1">
            </textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
</li>
<li class="gw-sortable-handle ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <textarea data-content-index="-2">
            </textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
</li>
<li class="gw-sortable-handle ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <textarea data-content-index="-3">
            </textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the whole li which has a div within another div that contains the textarea that has the data-content-index is equal to "-1" using jQuery.

Comment: Cant you just add an ID to the li you want to select? var li = $("#ID");

Comment: $('li div div textarea[data-content-index=-1]').closest('li') this should work .check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, but the selector is likely the same:

```
var index = -1;
var li = document.querySelector(
  `li > div > div > textarea[data-content-index="${index}"]`
).closest('li');
```

With *jQuery* you would `$('li > ....').closest('li')` and obtain the jQuery object instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you
Using vanilla javascript:

```
 document.querySelector(`li div div textarea[data-content-index='-1']`
).closest('li')
```

Using Jquery

```
$('li div div textarea[data-content-index=-1]').closest('li')
```